# Fractional change in volume from scale-factor

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, volume

I was given the following question which I am unable to get a seemingly correct answer from:

> A body expands linearly by a factor $\alpha$ due to an increase in temperature. Because of the expansion, a point at $\vec{r}$ is displaced to the point $\vec{r}+\vec{h}$. Calculate $\nabla \cdot \vec{h}$. By what fraction does the volume increase?

From the question we can deduce that:

$$\vec{r}+\vec{h}=\alpha\vec{r}$$

We can take the divergence of both sides and use the linearity of $\nabla$ to write:

$$\nabla \cdot (\vec{r}+\vec{h})=\alpha \nabla \cdot \vec{r}\implies \nabla \cdot \vec{r} + \nabla \cdot \vec{h} = \alpha(\nabla \cdot \vec{r})$$

We can then rearrange and use $\nabla \cdot \vec{r}=3$ to get:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{h}=3(\alpha - 1)$$

However, I am unsure how to use this to calculate the fractional volume increase. I tried:

$$\frac{V_{\text{new}}}{V_{\text{old}}}=\frac{\iiint_{V}\nabla\cdot\vec{h}\:\mathrm{d}V}{\iiint_{V}\:\mathrm{d}V}=3(\alpha - 1)$$

However, this is clearly wrong as we would expect the answer to be $\frac{V_{\text{new}}}{V_{\text{old}}} \in \mathcal{O}(\alpha^{3})$, so I'd appreciate any hints to get me back on the right track.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the fractional increase in volume is:

$$\frac{a^{3}V_{\text{old}}-V_{\text{old}}}{V_{\text{old}}}=a^{3}-1$$

We can write:

$$a^{3}-1=(1+(a-1))^3-1$$

Using the binomial expansion, $(1+x)^{n}=1+nx+\mathcal{O}(x^{2})$ we have:

$$a^{3}-1=1+3(a-1)+\mathcal{O}(a-1)^{2}-1=3(a-1)+\mathcal{O}(a-1)^{2}$$

If we have $a \approx 1$, then we have:

$$a^{3}-1\approx 3(a-1)$$

As required.